# Changing method behaviour in ruby

Tags: ruby, mixins

Here is a code sample from the ruby pickaxe book:

```
Class VowelFinder
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def each
    @string.scan(/[aeiou]/] do |vowel|
      yield vowel
    end
  end
end

vf = VowelFinder.new("the quick brown fox jumped")    
vf.inject(:+)        # => 'euiooue'
```

What I am having a hard time understanding is where the modified 'each' method comes into play? I assume inject is calling it at some point but don't understand why it's doing it, and how I could predict or emulate this behavior in my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `VowelFinder` class implements the *protocol* that is mandatory for the `Enumerable` module that you can include to gain a lot of ruby *iterator* methods: http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable

> The Enumerable mixin provides collection classes with several
>   traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. The
>   class must provide a method each, which yields successive members of
>   the collection. If Enumerable#max, #min, or #sort is used, the objects
>   in the collection must also implement a meaningful <=> operator, as
>   these methods rely on an ordering between members of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `inject` actually causes a call to `each`. The way `inject` works is by going over all the elements of the `Enumerable` using `each`, applying the passed operator to the `memo` and to the next value and storing the result back into `memo`. The result of the entire call is the value of `memo` in the end. You can see the documentation in [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that inject actually calls each method and the reason this happens is because inject actually uses each method internally. In fact, a lot if the Enumerable methods use the .each method; like #map, #select, #reject.

The reason for this is that .each is the actual method which allows looping in an Enumerable Object. The other methods are just so that things get easy for us, developers, and we don't have to use .each everywhere. Imagine having to write the above code using .each. It wouldn't be tough but vf.inject(:+) is definitely easier. So is the case with collect or map.

And the best way to implement this(as is done in Ruby) without repeating code is to have the other method call #each as there is no code duplication and each of #map or #collect or #inject does not have to traverse the Enumerable Object differently.

Genrally, I avoid using #each and there are so many other methods which makes our job easier. If you want to modify your array collection, it's advisable not to money-patch the #each method (unless, of course, you want all the other methods to change as well.)